# Outlook Add-ins closing when a new email is opened

Tags: outlook, outlook-addin

Whenever I have an add-in open in outlook, it closes immediately when I open a different email. Is there a way to keep an add-in open while I browse through multiple emails? Or is outlook coded in such a way that forces the add-in to close every time you click on a different email?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understand your questions you are the user of the Outlook Add-on. If this is correct, you will not be able to change this behavior. Every time you switch the item you would need to click to invoke the add-on once again. You may also contact the developers of this add-on and request them to [implement a pinnable taskpane](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/add-ins/pinnable-taskpane) with explanation of your business case.

Well, if I was wrong and you are the developer of this add-on, you should look at [pinnable taskpane](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/add-ins/pinnable-taskpane) in Outlook. This would cover exactly the case you have described. What you would need to do is just support `VersionOverrides v1.1` schema in your add-on manifest as well as register and implement the `Office.EventType.ItemChanged` event handler in your add-on JS implementation.